# ManyToOne Entity empty after flush but saved in Database correctly

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a ManyToOne connection between my `Offer`and my `OfferObject` entities (one offer can have many offerObjects):

**Offer**

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\OfferObject", mappedBy="offer")
 */
protected $offerObject;
```

**OfferObject**

```
/**
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Offer, inversedBy="offerObject")
*/
protected $offer;
```

Now I create an offer:

```
/* Create New Offer */
$offer = new Offer();
....    
$em->persist($offer);
```

and immediately I add OfferObjects like this:

```
foreach ($request->get('products') as $product) {
    $oo = new OfferObject();
    $oo->setOffer($offer);
    ....
    $em->persist($oo);
}
```

And finally I flush them:

```
try {
    $em->flush();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    ....
}
```

Everthing is in saved in the database as expected, but when I do this immediately after the `flush`, it shows nothing:

```
foreach($offer->getOfferObject() as $ob){
    echo $ob->getPrice()."<br />";
}
```

Do I have to do anything else before`displaying?

//EDIT
If I look manually for the last ID in the DB (in this case 16) it works as intended.

```
$offerFromDB = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Offer')->find(16);
foreach($offerFromDB->getOfferObject() as $ob){
    echo $ob->getPrice()."<br />";
}
```

Comment: Check mappedBy = "offer",  should be "product" on your mapping, and check the join condition on manyToOne relation. Check: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html

Comment: Copy pasted the wrong lines. Now fixed

Comment: $offer->getOfferObject()->getValues() because it returns a persistent collection. Try it.

Comment: This returns an empty array. I know its a persisent collection, that's why I did the foreach.

Comment: but you are not accessing to the persistent collection values, are you using getValues() ? regards

Comment: `dump($offer->getOfferObject()->getValues());` returns `[]`

Comment: have you tried var_dump($e->getMessage())?

Comment: The `flush` works fine, so there is no `$e`

Comment: add `$offer->addOfferObject($oo)` ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to fetch new `Offer` object by it's `id` from database. Or simply change your code like below:

```
foreach ($request->get('products') as $product) {
    $oo = new OfferObject();
    $oo->setOffer($offer);
    ....
    $em->persist($oo);

    $offer->addOfferObject($oo);
}
```